# Regex not matching String from a text file in Java

Tags: java, string

I have the following code and I do not know why, Regex does not match with the string coming from the file.

```
String s = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("training set", "fr-le-petit-prince.txt")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
System.out.println(s);  // Mon dessin ne representait pas un chapeau.

s = s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "").toLowerCase();
System.out.println(s);  // empty, but the value in debugger is : mon dessin ne representait pas un chapeau.

s = "TeSt";
s = s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "").toLowerCase();
System.out.println(s);  // test
```

Comment: What is the initial value of `s` and what is the output after it passes through the first `replaceAll`?

Comment: Either `readFile` returns an empty string (e.g. because the file *is* empty), or it throws an `IOException` leaving `s` empty. Try **debugging** your code, e.g. by printing the value of `s` *before* calling `replaceAll` the first time.

Comment: I edited the code to print an output just before the first `replaceAll`

Comment: I get "mon dessin ne representait pas un chapeau". also, it seems the `replaceAll()` doesn't make any change. if you remove the `.toLowerCase()` then the String reminas the same

Comment: the whole `readFile()` method is completely redundant since java 7 and can be replaced by one line `String text = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(folderName, fileName)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`

Comment: Thank you for the `readFile()` method. I updated the code. I don't understand, it seems the value in the debugger is good, but it does not display anything in console. Any idea ?

Comment: perhaps IDE is configured so that stdout is redirected to file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the problem was coming from my text file which was way too large. It does not contain only one sentence as you can see above, but a lot more. It seems that the String is too large and then is kind of invisible in eclipse console. However, if I copy and paste the invisible content of the console to notepad, it is correclty displayed. Same if I write the content into a file, it is good.

To solve it in Eclipse : go to Window > Preferences > Run/Debug > Console > Check width console and set a number. It appears !

Do not ask me why it works like that, I just found out by experimenting and I have no explanation for that.